# delete node in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

been reading docs and other posts but I am unable to remove a node. I am attempting to select the node by a value.

```
  var eventContactsRef = firebase.database().ref('events-contacts');
  eventContactsRef.orderByChild('eventContactId').equalTo(eventContactId);
```

then call the remove method on the result

```
 eventContactsRef.remove(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

nothing happens except a null error value. I am using the latest firebase, most examples are for older versions so I am unsure if I need to get the key and then attempt to delete with that as a reference?

This is the first time using firebase so I am not sure if I have saved the data correctly. here is code to save.

```
 var key = firebase.database().ref().child('event-contacts').push().key;
  var url = firebase.database().ref('/event-contacts/' + key);
  url.set(eventContacts);
```

and screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot remove a query itself. You can only remove **the results that match** a query.

```
var eventContactsRef = firebase.database().ref('events-contacts');
var query = eventContactsRef.orderByChild('eventContactId').equalTo(eventContactId);
query.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref.remove();
})
```

Comment: so i plugged in code and the query did reach the callback function . switch child_added to value and the function ran, but the snapshot was null. see update to post please

Comment: just caught typo. i had events-contacts instead of event-contacts. Everything works. thanks

Comment: Thanks, but i didn't need to search the ref I already had it.