# How to delete a node in firebase realtime database in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a difficult time deleting a node in a firebase realtime database.

This is what my firebase realtime database looks like:
[image]

This is what I tried, following [delete node in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488911/delete-node-in-firebase) and [How to delete/remove nodes on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537720/how-to-delete-remove-nodes-on-firebase):

1)

```
     let chatRef = db.ref("/chats");
      var query = chatRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(chatId);
      query.on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.ref.remove();
      });
```

With the above code, when I clicked to delete the entire data (all of the nodes, including chat) was deleted.

2)

```
      chatRef.limitToLast(1).once("value", (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((deedSnapshot) => {
          deedSnapshot.ref.remove();
        });
      });
```

I got this working as intended, but it only removes the last node in /chats, and I want to specify the `chat/uid` I want to remove.

3)

```
      let chatRef = db.ref("/chats");
      chatRef.child("5ZuZvUyByDcbteclgpM0t08beVn1").remove();
```

This simply caused nothing to happen. I had this in a try/catch, and clicking on "delete" led to the try running, but no errors were caught. And nothing happened in the database.

4)

```
      let chatRef = db.ref("/chats/MJy8cxO85ldEnDScsWZ");
      chatRef.remove();
```

Same outcome as number 3 above -- nothing happened, and no errors were caught in the try/catch.

UPDATE: I tried the following, but this removes the entire `chats` data instead of only the node I want deleted:

```
      let chatRef = db.ref("/chats");
      chatRef
        .orderByChild("uid")
        .equalTo(chatId)
        .once("value")
        .then(function (snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            //remove each child
            chatRef.child(childSnapshot.key).remove();
          });
        });
```

Comment: Your first attempt looks about right. The only thing I'd change is to use `.once("value", ...)` instead

Comment: Thanks Phil! I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441625/firebase-remove-node-based-on-child-value and tried my first attempt again, rewriting it slightly: 

```
      let chatRef = db.ref("/chats");
      chatRef
        .orderByChild("uid")
        .equalTo(chatId)
        .once("value")
        .then(function (snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            //remove each child
            chatRef.child(childSnapshot.key).remove();
          });
        });
```

However, this removes the entire data inside chats instead of the single node. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your fourth example should work, except you have a typo:

```
let chatRef = db.ref("/chats/MJy8cxO85ldEnDScsWZ");
```

It should instead be:

```
let chatRef = db.ref("/chats/-MJy8cxO85ldEnDScsWZ");
```

You're missing the "-" before "M".

Comment: Awesome, thank you! You're right, I didn't realize the `-M` was a part of the string. Do you know if there's an easy way to retrieve the key (e.g. `-MJy8cxO85ldEnDScsWZ`) based on the value of the `uid` (e.g. `5ZuZvUyByDcbteclgpM0t08beVn1`)?

Comment: Sure, you should learn how to perform a filter query as described in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Answer (score 2):

To remove a node in realtime database
First import remove from database

```
import { remove } from "firebase/database";
```

And in the delete methode you set :

```
remove(ref(getDatabase(), `users/${userId}/node/${node.id}`))
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I am bit late to the party. Just like to suggest another way.

To remove a node we can pass null as a value in `set`

```
import { database } from 'firebase-admin';

    const db = database();
        const ref = db.ref('server/saving-data/fireblog');
    
        dataRef.set(null, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Data could not be removed.' + error);
      } else {
        console.log('Data removed successfully.');
      }
    });
```